# How to control child component by click Material UI Icon in parent component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My goal is to control child component by Material UI Icon click in React with Typescript app.
So I wish to know that how to access to a child component with useState() or useRef() from a parent one. thank you in advanced.

```
//Parent.tsx as a parent component

...
import ChildComponent from '/FormDialog';

export default function ParentComponent() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
  ...
    <ChildCareIcon />    // a Material UI Icon
  ...
  )



//Child.tsx as a child component

...
export default function ChildComponent() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open form dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      >
    ...
  );
```

Comment: If you want the element to be controlled by the parent, wouldn't you just make `open` and `setOpen` as props instead of state? Then it becomes state of the parent and passed in to child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't declare the same-named property already defined in the API and inject it. So I solved it by replacing the trigger with the icon that I want to make as below.

```
//Parent.tsx as a parent component

...
import ChildComponent from '/FormDialog';

export default function ParentComponent() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
  ...
  // <ChildCareIcon />    // move to child component as trigger button.
    <ChildComponent />
  ...
  )



//Child.tsx as a child component

import ChildCareIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChildCare'; 
...
export default function ChildComponent() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      //<Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
      //  Open form dialog
      //</Button>

      // injected from parent component with onClick method.
      <ChildCareIcon onClick={handleClickOpen} fontSize="inherit" />    
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      >
    ...
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `[open,setOpen]` in parent and pass as props to the child

```js
//Parent.tsx as a parent component

...
import ChildComponent from '/FormDialog';

export default function ParentComponent() {

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
  ...
    <ChildComponent open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
    <ChildCareIcon />     // a Material UI Icon
  ...
  )



//Child.tsx as a child component

...
export default function ChildComponent({open,setOpen}) {

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open form dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      >
    ...
  );
```

or else use them in context

Comment: Set That Props for ```ChildComponent```